# How to run a Java Gradle project from VSCodium with the Redhat plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, redhat, sdkman

Having installed the `redhat` plugin for `Java` on `Linux`:

[image: redhat]

how do I now run the app:

[image: chimp]

from `VSCodium`?

From the console, the app builds and runs fine using gradle.

After closing `VSCodium` and then restarting (both the machine and IDE) I see:

[image: no_java]

I've installed `Java` and the `JDK` with `SDK` so:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sdk install java 11.0.9.hs-adpt

java 11.0.9.hs-adpt is already installed.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ javac -version
javac 11.0.9.1
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1, mixed mode)
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

probably this is the problem.  Perhaps the `IDE` isn't picking up on the `JDK`?

Comment: Do you mean to run gradle projects by clicking button or some options instead of running commands in Terminal?

Comment: thanks, @MollyWang I added some additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you've built the project successfully.

This is a demo gradle project, and you can click the **Run** or **button** in the top right-hand corner:

[image]

Comment: I think it's because I'm using SDKman to install java and the JDK.

Comment: You can create a gradle project,which is simple and as the same as the one in my answer to test if SDKman affects project's creation: open Command Platte--> Java:Create Java Project--> Spring Boot--> Gradle Project--> 2.4.0--> Java-->keep the default and press Enter--> keep the default and press Enter --> JAR--> 11--> Select dependencies( Spring Boot Dev Tools;Lombok; Spring Web; Thymeleaf)--> Choose generation folder, then open it. Can you get the result like the above screenshot?